# Recommended way of sending emails from React application? (php / node)

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, email, nodemailer

I a sorry, I am an absolute beginner with React & the web. I have made this website with React and I have a form on there, so the visitor can send me emails.

I would usually have done this with a php POST, but now, using React-Router, I don't know how to send the POST variable to the php server. How would I do the same thing with React? Will I need a nodejs email server, or can I somehow use php with React -what's the recommended & easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't really dictate any way to do this. You could render a `<form>` with an `action`:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
```

Or you could call an async API (using XHR or fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much email functionality your app uses, I would recommend the Mailgun service. It has a really easy to use node API.
[Link to Mailgun landing page](https://www.mailgun.com/?utm_term=mailgun&utm_campaign=751081136&utm_content=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI14Px8fW21gIVAUSGCh2MkABEEAAYASAAEgJWIPD_BwE)